# LUIS issues with special characters

Tags: botframework, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

`(TEXT)` is converted to `( TEXT )` in LUIS when we identify an entity name. 
Issues with special characters.

Refer the image in below:

[image: Special_charater_Issue.PNG]

Here monthly iq dashboard `hospitalists` is converted to `reportname --> "monthly iq dashboard ( hospitalists )"` in `Entities`. So when we use this entity in bot framework we are facing issues while comparing to actual report name stored in Metadata (database).

Comment: "... with special characters" just means this case, or there exists any other case?

Comment: Not sure if this is an issue or the "normal" behaviour of LUIS. If you have a look to utterances with punctuation, there are always spaces added. Can't you handle that in your code ?

Comment: as @NicolasR has said, this is "normal" behaviour from my experience. I have a method that takes in the utterance, and "sanitizes" this type of phrases.  I have seen this experience with commas and parens.  Depending on how your entities break down, you may just need to do a regex type replace to remove the whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

> `(TEXT)` is converted to `( TEXT )` in LUIS when we identify an entity name. Issues with special characters.

The issue you reported seems be that whitespace is added when some special characters are using, I reproduced the issue on my side, and I find similar issues are reported by others:

- [LUIS inserts whitespace in utterances when punctuation present causing entity getting incorrectly parsed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38679611/luis-inserts-whitespace-in-utterances-when-punctuation-present-causing-entity-ge)
- [LUIS cannot take care of special characters](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-LUIS-Windows/issues/54)

> when we use this entity in bot framework we are facing issues while comparing to actual report name stored in Metadata (database)

To solve it, as Nicolas R and NiteLordz mentioned in comments, you can try to handle that in your code. And to remove whitespace from `( hospitalists )`, the following regex would be helpful.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\(\s\w*\s\)");

input = Regex.Replace(input, regex.ToString(), c => c.Value.Replace(" ", ""));
```

**Note**: can reproduce the issue, and same issue will appear when we process something like URL that contains `/` and `.` etc

[image]