# Pattern Entity Luis

Tags: entity, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am trying to create a chat bot with the bot framework and luis. The main question that I have is that I wanted to know if I could create an entity that would pick up on a certain pattern. For example, I a bunch of id codes structured in the same way. It starts with 'ESI-' than 6 numbers broken up into 3 numbers then a dash then the other 3 - '421-123'. So the codes will look like this 'ESI-421-123'. So is it possible to create an entity that will pick up on this feature or do I have to input every id code as part a of list entity.

Thank you

Comment: In general case, Luis should be able to learn patterns by some utterances, and we don't need to say all values to LUIS.

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to create an entity that will pick up on this feature or do I have to input every id code as part a of list entity.

For your scenario, creating a **Simple** entity is ok. I agree with OmG, you do not have to add all id codes. If you add some example utterances and label entity `IdCode` in utterances, and train your LUIS app, it should be able to recognize the user’s input id code as the corresponding entity.

In my test, the id code `ESI-123-567` does not exist in example utterances, LUIS still can recognize it as entity `IdCode`.

[image]

The whitespace will be added beacuse the specific character `-` is used in id code, which might cause unexpected issue in your bot app, to solve it, you can try to use a regex to remove the whitespaces in your bot code, this SO thread:[LUIS issues with special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48145790/luis-issues-with-special-characters/48181143#48181143)
 discussed about this issue, you can refer to it.

**Note**:

- For detailed information of building a LUIS app, please refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/add-intents).
- The section “When to use phrase lists instead of list entities” in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/LUIS/luis-concept-feature), compare phrase lists with list entities, which can help us know when to use list entities.